# In Boxtrolls, are the boxes a natural part of troll society or is this a peculiar adaptation for this tribe?

Tags: boxtrolls

In the movie, *Boxtrolls*, the trolls are apparently highly attached to their boxes, never seen without them, and reacting in horror when Eggs falls out of his.

> Of course, by the end, we've learned that they can leave them if they so choose.

I know this is partially based on a book, ''Here Be Monsters!'', so it might be elaborated upon there. Are boxes a normal part of troll society? This particular group seems to be quite adapted to them. Or is it just this tribe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The official explanation can be found in the page "Johnson's Taxonomy of Trolls & Creatures" of the [site](http://www.here-be-monsters.com/About-the-Books.php) for 'Here be Monsters!':

> Boxtrolls: A sub-species of the common troll, they are very shy, so live inside a box.

So yes, this is a particular aspect of this tribe and I guess an invention by the author of the book. For sure they cannot be found in classic mythology, cardboard boxes didn't exist, and I couldn't find any species of trolls that liked to cover itself with something equivalent to boxes. So they are a very shy evolution of common trolls (the small, nocturnal and catty kind) developed in an urban environment.

Comment: Good enough for me. :)